# How can I remove all slide transitions from a Keynote presentation?

Tags: keynote

I have received a powerpoint file where every single slide has a 1 second dissolve transition applied. I would like to remove all of the transitions so that there aren't any, and the slides just change immediately with no transition.

I know how to do this one slide at a time slowly by hand, but there are a very large number of slides and this would take too long. Is there a way to automatically fix all the slides at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently; this worked for me:

1. Use the "Navigator" view (View menu > Navigator), which shows slide thumbnails on the left side of the window.
2. Show the animation inspector (View menu > Inspector > Animate); it opens on the right side of the window.
3. Select one of the slide thumbnails (on the left), then press Command-A to select all of them.
4. Make sure you have the entire slides selected, not content within them. All thumbnails should have yellow outlines indicating that they're selected, and there shouldn't be anything highlighted in the slide view (the middle part of the window). Also, make sure the animation inspector is showing "Transitions" (what happens between slides) rather than "Build In" "Action" "Build Out" (what happens within a slide). If it's not, recheck you have the thumbnails selected not content within a particular slide.
5. In the animation inspector, click the "Change" button, then choose "None" from the popup menu that appears.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I thought I had tried that and for some reason couldn't figure out how to select all of the slides at once and still be able to modify the transition.

Comment: what about individual effects within a slide?